# Partial validation executed

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to do few validations in a form and it is not up to the mark. I need to hide the error message message of the name and show only email error. But it is not happening. Maybe you will understand from the code.

Here it is.

```
function validateform(form){ 
 event.preventDefault();
 console.log(form);
 var i; 
 var fname = form.name.value;
 var email = form.email.value;
 var message = form.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
 var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
 var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
 if (fname==null || fname==""){      
   for (i = 0; i < message.length;i++)
   {
     form.getElementsByClassName("error-message")[i].innerHTML="Please Enter Name";
  return false;
  }  
}

 else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
 for (i = 0; i < message.length;i++)
 {
  form.getElementsByClassName("error-email")[i].innerHTML="The email address you've entered contains an incorrect character. Please check this information and try again.";
  return false;
 } 
}

else if (fname!=null || fname!=""){
for (i = 0; i < message.length;i++)
 {
  form.getElementsByClassName("error-message")[i].style.display = "none";
  return false;
 }
}
```

HTML

```
    <form name="ccform" method="post" onsubmit="validateform(this)">
            <p class="customer-name">Name</p>
            <input type="text" class="input-name" name="name"></input>
            <p class="error-message"></p>
            <p class="customer-name">Email</p>
            <input type="text" class="input-name" name="email" placeholder="e.g. name@emailaddress.com"></input>
            <p class="error-email"></p>
            <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I want to hide error-message and show only error-email when name is entered,email is not entered and i press submit button.

P.S: Please no jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You have trying to hide `error_message` class in an `else if` condition. The code will not parse through all the `if` conditions. In your case, you want to show the email validation message and hence it will enter the second condition and will not enter the third condition. Refer the usage of `if-else if-else` statement [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_ifelse.htm). You just try to merge the second and third condition together as follows.

```
if (fname==null || fname==""){
    for (i = 0; i < message.length;i++)
    {
        form.getElementsByClassName("error-message")[i].innerHTML="Please Enter Name";
        form.getElementsByClassName("error-message")[i].style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }  
} else {
    form.getElementsByClassName("error-message")[i].style.display = "none";
}

if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < message.length;i++)
    {
        form.getElementsByClassName("error-email")[i].innerHTML="The email address you've entered contains an incorrect character. Please check this information and try again.";
        form.getElementsByClassName("error-email")[i].style.display = "block";
        return false;
    } 
} else {
    form.getElementsByClassName("error-email")[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this but now this condition doesnot satisfy if you follow these steps:
1. Enter name and press enter.
2. Error-email will come up.
3. Enter valid email and remove name and press submit.
4. Error-message needs to be populated in this case

Comment: Any other logic if you find for validation then i will be happy to use it but not jQuery

Comment: @MainakBhattacharjee Answer Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
function validateform(form){ 
var i; 
var fname = form.name.value;
var email = form.email.value;
var message = form.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf("."); 
if (fname==null || fname==""){      
for (i = 0; i < message.length;i++)
 {
  form.getElementsByClassName("error-message")[i].innerHTML="Please enter your name";
  form.getElementsByClassName("error-message")[i].style.display = "block";
  form.getElementsByClassName("error-email")[i].style.display = "none";
  return false;
 }  
}

if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
for (i = 0; i < message.length;i++)
 {
  form.getElementsByClassName("error-email")[i].innerHTML="The email address you've entered contains an incorrect character. Please check this information and try again.";
  form.getElementsByClassName("error-message")[i].style.display = "none";
  form.getElementsByClassName("error-email")[i].style.display = "block";  
  return false;
 } 
}
```